# Mysql Distinct rows 2 columns

Tags: mysql

I have a query:

```
SELECT p.productid, p.dupproductid
FROM products p, categories c
WHERE c.catid = p.catid && (c.parent IN(2257) || p.catid = 2257)
GROUP BY p.productid
```

This returns:

```
productid dupproductid
23423     0
54345     0
34234     33333
23423     33333
45345     0
34324     11111
46546     0
```

I want to only get unique dupproductid apart from the ones that are 0 so I can't use GROUP BY

I'd like it to return

```
productid dupproductid
23423     0
54345     0
34234     33333
45345     0
34324     11111
46546     0
```

Comment: Is it mandatory to drop only the second row or the min productid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to drop the min ID then this will work for you -

```
SELECT p.productid, p.dupproductid
FROM (SELECT p.productid
            ,p.dupproductid
            ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY dupproductid ORDER BY productid DESC) as RN
      FROM products p, categories c
      WHERE c.catid = p.catid && (c.parent IN(2257) || p.catid = 2257)
      ) T
WHERE T.productid = 0 
OR RN = 1
```

Sql Fiddle for you - 
http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!18/db18b/2

Answer (score 0):

Can you not do a "select DISTINCT" or does this not help you? If not can you say exactly what you would like your table to show? I am confused as to wether you still wish to show the rows that return "0"? Can you give me some more information?

Comment: Unfortunately i am fairly new to SQL however i don't think this would be possible in an SQL Query i think you will have to do this inside the DB. Somebody may come along and correct me but i'm pretty confident, thanks

Comment: @connorg98, There is nothing that you cant do with a query. Whatever you can think, SQL is capable of doing so.

Comment: @AnkitBajpai I just thought that because it is the same number in the same column (data) and there isn't a way that i can think of that allows you to exclude dupes :/ thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

just use min aggregate function, As you keep the 0 on result set

```
 SELECT p.productid, min(p.dupproductid) as dupproductid
    FROM products p, categories c
    WHERE c.catid = p.catid && (c.parent IN(2257) || p.catid = 2257)
    GROUP BY p.productid
```

Comment: @Tom does it helps ?

Comment: No that returns the same result

Comment: @Tom can you please share your products and categories  table data , i think  problem will be solved easily if share those records set